# Weird behaviour in `WhenEvent`

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

Consider the following code (taken from [question 158857](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158857/two-bouncing-balls-in-1-dimension-issues-with-two-different-methods)):

```
g = 9.81;
eqs = {x1''[t] + g == 0, x2''[t] + g == 0};
ci = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 2, x1'[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 0};
events := {WhenEvent[x1[t] == 0, x1'[t] -> -x1'[t]],
  WhenEvent[x2[t] == x1[t], v1 = x1'[t]; x1'[t] -> x2'[t]],
  WhenEvent[x2[t] == x1[t], (* -> *) 1; (* <- *) x2'[t] -> v1]}
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs~Join~ci~Join~events, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 5}]

Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

It returns

[image]

The first `WhenEvent` accounts for the bouncing on the ground ($y=0$) while the other two aims at exchanging the derivatives.

Now if I remove the `1;` in the last `WhenEvent`, I get the following error

> NDSolveValue::nlnum1: The function value {v1} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} when the arguments are {0.790166,0.9375,1.10736,0.9375,-7.75153}.

Why is only working if I add something before `x1'[t] -> x2'[t]` ?
I tried on MMA 11.0 and 10.3.

Comment: `Module[{}, x2'[t] -> v1]` makes it work as well. Odd.

Comment: you can also do this more cleanly with a single `WhenEvent` : `{x1'[t], x2'[t]} -> {x2'[t], x1'[t]}]`  ( not really answering the question though )

Comment: @george2079 1. Strange. 2. I thought that was the first thing I had tried. So much simpler... Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that the order that the two identical events are dealt with differs.  If I insert a `Print` statement into the first `x2[t]==x1[t]` event, that is printed after the error message (so in fact, `v1` hasn't been defined yet).

Comment: @ChrisK And isn't that strange?!

Comment: @anderstood A little bit strange.  I tried the `"Priority"` option of `WhenEvent`, but that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: In v9.0.1 there's no warning, but the result is wrong: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lUQGO.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope my answer does not come too late. You should include v1 into `DiscreteVariables`

```
g = 9.81;
eqs = {x1''[t] + g == 0, x2''[t] + g == 0};
ci = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 2, x1'[0] == 0, x2'[0] == 0, v1[0] == 0};
events := {WhenEvent[x1[t] == 0, x1'[t] -> -x1'[t]], 
  WhenEvent[
   x2[t] == x1[t], {v1[t] -> x1'[t], x1'[t] -> x2'[t], 
    x2'[t] -> v1[t]}]}
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs~Join~ci~Join~events, {x1, x2, v1}, {t, 0, 5}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> v1]
Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]