# Encoding spatial data in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I am doing some experimentation with machine learning and robotics, and want Mathematica to be my primary platform. For it, I need to represent a room with some obstacles (circles) and a goal (square). These obstacles and goal could be anywhere, and I need my simnulated robot to be able to travel around in this room and collide with obstacles.

My question is, what is the best way to represent this spatial data? Are there built-in methods for designating objects with a position, or even a velocity, in space and then getting information about them later? Or am I better off just trying to represent these obstacles and goal as a list of radii and positions and calculating/drawing everything myself?

Comment: There are some related Wolfram Demonstration [projects](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=robot) that might help.

Comment: You can see in my answer on [bouncy bubbles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124930/731) how I like to represent such objects.

Comment: It's hard to give more specific advice when the question is so general by the way.

Comment: @C.E. You’re completely right. This question would be an easy one if Mathematica has a built in library for such tasks, but it seems that it does not, so it’s very hard to give an answer in the general case. But your link is super helpful and tells me pretty much what I need to know - find some clean way of representing objects through arrays of positions and metadata.